# MongoDb findOneAndUpdate() concurrency multiple consumers

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, concurrency, findandmodify

I am new to mongodb and using a mongodb database collection for my simple queueing system. I want to be able to run multiple instances of my consumer. I am using the `findOneAndUpdate()` operation to pick up a job a pending job and mark it processing before processing it. If I have multiple instances of the consumer running is there any case that consumers running concurrently would pick the same job. I am using the native mongodb js driver

My consumer code looks as follows

```js
const job = await db.collections('jobs').findOneAndUpdate({ status: 'pending'},
    { $set: { status: "processing" } }
);
```